# Kafka source connect job restart with updated config, but the task still used the old config

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect source job and noticed a very weird behavioral. After I restarted the source job with updated configuration. The task was still using the old configuration to run one pull and the task got config update and restarted with the new config. See below logs for some example. Any one has similar experiense or know how to resolve this issue?

```
[2020-11-11 06:58:29,174] INFO [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source|worker] RestSourceConnectorConfig values: 
    batch.enable = true
    batch.subject.area = baw_demo
    batch.table.id = cmdb_ci_database
    batch.uow = 20170304000000  **
    batch.uow.end = 20170304010000  **
...
[2020-11-11 06:58:29,188] INFO [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source|task-0] RestSourceConnectorConfig values: 
    batch.enable = true
    batch.subject.area = baw_demo
    batch.table.id = cmdb_ci_database
    batch.uow = 20170303040000  **
    batch.uow.end = 20170303050000 **
...
[2020-11-11 06:58:29,667] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] Tasks [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source-0] configs updated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1418)
[2020-11-11 06:58:30,169] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] Handling task config update by restarting tasks [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:581)
[2020-11-11 06:58:30,168] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1132)
[2020-11-11 06:58:30,169] INFO [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source|task-0] Stopping task baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:704)
[2020-11-11 06:58:31,074] INFO [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1182)
[2020-11-11 06:58:31,076] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:222)
[2020-11-11 06:58:31,076] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:552)
[2020-11-11 06:58:31,081] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-framework-test] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 604 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1111)
...
[2020-11-11 06:58:31,090] INFO [baw_demo-cmdb_ci_database-source|task-0] RestSourceConnectorConfig values: 
    batch.enable = true
    batch.subject.area = baw_demo
    batch.table.id = cmdb_ci_database
    batch.uow = 20170304000000 **
    batch.uow.end = 20170304010000 **
```

Comment: are you using distributed or standalone mode? how did you change the configuration?

Comment: We are running in distribted mode. The steps we took are: Deleted the job -> update the job configuration json file -> start the job with updated json.

Comment: One more context, the previous run didn't commit any record. I'm reading the comments in the KafkaConfigBackingStore.java and found below statement -- "we must buffer config updates for a connector's tasks and only apply atomically them once a commit message has been read.". But my assumption is if the job deleted, the task config should be deleted too. Rerun the job should bring a refresh new task with updated config but not the old one. Not sure why it's not case.

Comment: Hey @Orlando - did you manage to solve it and re-create with new config for tasks?

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a Kafka Connect connector, its status remains on the internal topics used to store information about it. If you create a new connector *with the same name* it will continue processing from the point at which the previous instance of the connector reached.

Therefore, create the new job instance with a new connector name, and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Robin for explanation. But why it's behavioral like this? Rename connector might work for source but sink will have issue with the consumer offset.

Comment: Isn't it a source connector you're running? For a sink connector you can update config for an existing connector, or create a new one, depending on the offset behaviour that you want

Comment: I kind of know the work around here. But I still don't understand why config update on job level doesn't affect task for a fresh start. The delete job shouldn't close out all the task?